# The slope of a graph

Tags: voltage, current, homework

What does the slope in this graph present
[image]

I know this might be a silly question, but my answer was:

> slope = VI = Pw (Pw is power)

And the answer in my text book was differet from mine, it was:

> slope = -r (r is the internal resistance of the battery)

And I think the book answer was related with the equation:

> Vb = V -Ir (where Vb is the emf of the battery, V is the voltage across the battery, (I) is the intensity of current and r is the internal resistnce.

So, are the two answers correct? Or it is only one?

Comment: Remember the slope formula ? Can you guess the units for the expression $$\dfrac{V}{I}$$ ?

Comment: Slope = \$\Delta y/\Delta x\$, so \$V/I\$ in this case.  Now, what's Ohm's Law say about \$V/I\$?

Comment: For this formula it will be V/A and this equals ohm Ω, but my graph show an inverse proportionality, and the formula you gave is for direct proportionality. @Hiiii

Comment: Hey slope "formula" doesn't depend on how the graph looks. It is always this : slope = (change in y) / (change in x)

Comment: @Hiiii, oh, Ok, I got it.

Comment: @Asmaa look at the vertical y axis. What is the label on this axis ?

Comment: Okay good :) Feel free to ask if something doesn't make sense with the slope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The slope of a graph goes as follows:

[image: slope=dx/dy]

The voltage is here on the Y-axis and the current is on the X-axis.
As I grows (so dx > 0), V decreases (dy<0). If you enter this in the formula you get.

[image: slope=-V/I]

Ohm's law states that [image: R=V/I].

So this means that the slope of this curve equals -R.

Answer (score 1):

Um..slope = \$\Delta V/\Delta I\$

Ohms law states \$V = IR\$

=> \$R = V/I\$

=> Slope = \$R\$

Since the slope is down the resistance is minus.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is wrong.
Slope of that graph is V/I which is the resistance. 
-R as it's -ve slope.
The answer given in your textbook is absolutely correct.
For a cell with internal resistance the voltage available is given by that equation.

Comment: The internal resistance of a battery is not negative.

Comment: Of course not. But the slope of the graph is. The discussion was about the slope. The slope is -V/I and V/I is R so it's -R.

Answer (score 0):

Its a loadline for determining amplification of tubes or fets or bipolars

[image]